# Rolling mean output without leading NAs in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to calculate right rolling mean on my lists of data using `rollmean()` function from package `zoo` in R. I want my output to exclude NAs at the beginning, and only lists the calculated rolling mean values.

my original time series data looks like this:

```
> ts_qtr[1:2] 
$`A`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017    0    0    0    0
2018    0    0    0    0
2019    0    0    1    0
2020    0    0          

$`B`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017    0    1    0    0
2018    0    0    0    0
2019    0    0    0    0
2020    0    0
```

When i run this line of code:
`cma_qtr <- lapply(ts_qtr, function(x) rollmean(x, k = 4, fill = NA, align = "right"))` 
, i get this kind of output with leading NAs:

```
> cma_qtr[1:2]
$`A`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017   NA   NA   NA 0.00
2018 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2019 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25
2020 0.25 0.25          

$`B`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017   NA   NA   NA 0.25
2018 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
2019 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2020 0.00 0.00
```

I want my output to look like this (without NAs):

```
$`A&R SANDWICHES INC.BARIATRIC`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017                0.00
2018 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2019 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25
2020 0.25 0.25          

$`AAA Carolinas.BARIATRIC`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017                0.25
2018 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
2019 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2020 0.00 0.00
```

If i run my line of code and state fill=FALSE, the leading values become 0 instead of NA (not exactly what i want either)

```
cma_qtr2 <- lapply(ts_qtr, function(x) rollmean(x, k = 4, fill = FALSE, align = "right"))

> cma_qtr2[1:2]
$`A`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2018 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2019 0.00 0.00 0.25 0.25
2020 0.25 0.25          

$`B`
     Qtr1 Qtr2 Qtr3 Qtr4
2017 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.25
2018 0.25 0.00 0.00 0.00
2019 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
2020 0.00 0.00
```

If i don't list fill and aline, i get an error message:

```
> cma_qtr3 <- lapply(ts_qtr, function(x) rollmean(x, k = 4))
 Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations
```

I am puzzled what to do next. Eventually i want to run rolling mean output through `predict()` or `forecast()` (from package `forecast` ) functions which through a warning message because of NAs.

Comment: Please follow the instructions for posting at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular the part about `dput`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using `na.rm = True` on your dataframe to maintain the rwos but exclude them from calculations.  You could also try `na.omit()` or `!is.na()` as a condition of your rolling mean.

You can see how it works here where they calculate the mean of columns excluding NA values. https://www.programmingr.com/tutorial/na-rm/

Comment: sorry, but  your solution won't work. I don't have NAs in my input data so na.omit is not applicable for rollmean. `